# Grep replace in multiple xml files

Tags: 14.04, command-line, grep, sed, xml

I have below command to find all the `.xml` files containing the `<active>true</active>` having `<codePool>community</codePool>` after that line on next line.

```
grep -rzl '<active>true</active>.*<codePool>community</codePool>' --include='*.xml' --color=always
```

Now how to combine this with `sed` to replace `true` string inside the `<active>...` tag to `false` string along those matched lines ?

Comment: Watch out, you might get an answer from this guy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5851520 :-)

Comment: ... which is why you have the `-z` in there. Good, good...

Comment: Question: that grep will detect files where the codePool/community thing is  anywhere in the file after the active bit. Is that ok? You say "on the next line", but the grep isn't caring about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer @glennjackman, I was also successfull achieving my requirement with the following code, it is vulnerable in-case the input changes, but it will be consistent keeping the fixed directory structure and file format of xml files of Magento, in mind:

```
for filename in *.xml; do
    if grep -q '<codePool>community</codePool>' "$filename"; then
        if [[ $filename != *"Mage_"* ]]; then
            sed -i.bak 's/<active>true<\/active>/<active>false<\/active>/g' "$filename"
        fi
    fi
done
```

This way I was also able to backup those files first, that were going to be modified, just the way I wanted.

Hope this simplifies things and redirects all/as many as possible people to using domestic libraries rather than installing third party tools which aren't allowed to install on Remote SSH/VPN networks.

Answer (score 2):

You should use XML parsing tools for XML data. [`xmlstarlet`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xmlstarlet.1.html) is a good choice. Regular expressions are just not powerful enough ([canonical reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552))

If your data looks like:

```
<root>
  <foo>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>private</codePool>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>community</codePool>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Then

```
xmlstarlet ed --update '//active[.="true" and ../codePool="community"]' -v false file.xml
```

produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>private</codePool>
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <active>false</active>
    <codePool>community</codePool>
  </foo>
</root>
```

---

Here's an awk program that does what you request. Keep in mind that it's fragile: if the input changes, this code will stop working. It does just use plain string operations.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        marker = "<codePool>community</codePool>"
        srch = "<active>true</active>"
        repl = "<active>false</active>"
    }
    index($0, marker) {
        i = index(prev, srch)
        if (i > 0) 
            prev = substr(prev, 1, i-1) repl substr(prev, i+length(srch))
    }
    {
        if (prev) print prev
        prev = $0
    }
    END {if (prev) print prev}
'
```

Comment: That _canonical reference_ needs updating for XHTML->"XML generally". I fear the original author was eaten by Tony the Pony.

Comment: @glennjackman, Your answer is quite well, but I am working on Remote SSH that is owned by client, so I don't have permission to install any third party software/library into his system. Please suggest also a ubuntu or any well-known linux command line alternative to this.